# Chart on Frozen Cells in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

Is it possible to place a chart outside the scrollable part of a google sheet when some rows and columns are frozen. I tried removing the frozen panels first, creating the chart and freezing columns and rows again but the chart tends to move back to the scrollable part of the table.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Charts cannot be placed in a frozen section of the sheet. One workaround is to use a [sparkline()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093289) formula that can insert simple line charts and bar charts in a cell. Use **Format > Merge cells** to create a larger area for a sparkline chart.